# parsing unstructured files with r

Tags: regex, r

I'm trying to parse this unstructured file using R

ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/pub/misc/movies/database/genres.list.gz

```
Deadpoint (2012)     Action
Deadpoint (2012)     Drama
Deadpoint (2012)     Short
Deadpoint (2016)     Action
Deadpoint (2016)     Adventure
Deadpoint (2016)     Drama
Deadpoint (2016)     Horror
Deadpoint (2016)     Short
Deadpool (2013) (VG)     Action
Deadpool (2013) (VG)     Comedy
Deadpool (2013) (VG)     Fantasy
Deadpool (2016)      Action
Deadpool (2016)      Adventure
Deadpool (2016)      Comedy
Deadpool (2016)      Romance
Deadpool (2016)      Sci-Fi
Deadpool 2 (2018)     Action
Deadpool 2 (2018)     Adventure
Deadpool 2 (2018)     Comedy
Deadpool 2 (2018)     Fantasy
```

I posted the sample as code as I cannot post it in the proper format over here but it's movie title (including year), a VARIABLE number of tabs and a one word Genre.

I want to capture the movie title in 1 column and the genre in the last column. With regex I would do it like this:

```
^(.*?)\t+(\S+)$
```

I tried to read_lines from the gzip and `gsub("\t+","\t",lines)` but then read.table would not read the cleaned variable.

```
read.table(lines, header = FALSE, sep = "\t", quote = "\"", fill = TRUE, comment.char = "", skip=380)
```

Using the code above I get the movie title in the first column and the genre in one of 6 further columns according to the number of tabs the line has. Any ideas on alternatives how to get this done.

Comment: What do you mean by "but then read.table would not read the cleaned variable." ?

Comment: What's `(VG)` mean?

Comment: If the file is irregular then readLines is less likely to prompt an error message and then you can post-process the lines that meet your requirements.

Comment: @SebastianLenartowicz (VG) means video games ie not a movie (imdb reviews them too).

Comment: @steveb when i readlines - ex. lines <- readlines(file.txt) and clean lines with then i cannot read.table(lines) as it gives errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come up with the following solution

```
genres<-read.table(genres.list.gz, header = FALSE, sep = "\t", quote = "\"", fill = TRUE, comment.char = "", skip=starts+2)
x<-paste(genres[,2],genres[,3],genres[,4],genres[,5],genres[,6],genres[,7])
x<-gsub("\\s+", "", x)
genres[,2:7]<-NULL
genres[,2]<-x
names(genres) <- c("Title", "Genre")
```

First I create a vector x with the genre columns all concatenated, Second I remove all whitespace from all entries

Then I remove all columns from the genres data.frame and set x as the 2nd column

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you read up the file into an array called `line,` try the below. It implements your regex with R's little quirks adjusted. Your regex doesn't take into account that some films have stuff between the year and the genre (e.g. "Angel City (2011) {{SUSPENDED}} Drama"), but it doesn't occur that often.

```
line <- gsub('\"', '', line)     # delete quotes
line <- gsub('\\t',' ', line)    # tabs into spaces
line <- gsub(' {2,}', ' ', line) # delete extra spaces
line <- regmatches(line,regexpr('^(.*?)\\s(\\S+)$',line))
```

It takes a while to run through 2.3 million lines, but it works

Answer (score 1):

The following code splits the data into 2 columns.

I use tibble and tidyr to split the data.

```
library(readr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)

data <- read_lines("genres.list.gz", skip = 380)

data <- gsub('\"', '', data)     # delete quotes
data <- gsub('\\t+','~', data)    # replace tabs with a ~ 


movies <- data %>% 
  # turn into tibble data_frame. avoids stringsAsFactors = FALSE 
  # name column movie 
  data_frame(movie = .) %>%  
  # split movie column based on "~"
  separate(movie, c("movie", "genre"), "~", extra = "merge")

#clean up workspace
rm(lines) 

head(movies)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
                     movie       genre
                     <chr>       <chr>
1            !Next? (1994) Documentary
2         #1 Single (2006)  Reality-TV
3    #15SecondScare (2015)      Horror
4    #15SecondScare (2015)       Short
5    #15SecondScare (2015)    Thriller
6 #1MinuteNightmare (2014)      Horror
```